# Integration between Salesforce Feedback Management and Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, salesforce-survey, interactive-email

Is there a standard way to do that? Or would the only way be to send the survey link in an email that sends in a journey?
Is there a standard way to connect the interactive email block from emails to the feedback management?